# Why border is not changing on hover?

Tags: css, hover, border

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   p:hover{border:2px solid red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <p style="border:2px solid green;">This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am confused: why is the border color not changing on hover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inline styles have a higher priority than any CSS rule that is not `!important`. So the solution is to mark the attributes in the `p:hover` rule as important:

```
p:hover {
    border:2px solid red !important;
}
```

Another option would be moving the initial style into the `<style>` tag, too.

```
p {
    border: 2px solid green;
}

p:hover {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637380/298479) is a TL;DR-style explanation of CSS priorities and if you prefer something a bit longer you can also have a look at the [relevant part of the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).

Comment: You really shouldn't use important

Comment: Maybe he's stuck with that HTML code for some reason. In this case there wouldn't be another choice but to use `!important`.

Comment: Is it really necessary that `p:hover` is declared _after_ `p`?

Comment: He could increase the specificity of the `hover` tag

Comment: You can't be more specific than an inline `style` attribute except by using `!important`... @drahnr: Nope.. just tested it and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its really good to know this `!important`.

Answer (score 2):

Inline styles have a higher priority than separate css sections

EDIT: *sigh* 2nd - just a tad too slow.

This should work - as far as I know `!important` is not considered good practice, so I'd suggest to use this approach:

```
<style type="text/css">
p{border:2px solid green;}
p:hover{border:2px solid red;}
</style>
<body>
<p>foobar</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have access to the CSS (say, because another department owns the HTML, or it's being introduced through another method), you'll have to use `!important`. Use of `!important` is absolutely fine, as it was intended to be a remedy to situations exactly like this. The idea of it being "bad practice" is wrong (unless you're using it to be lazy about your CSS specificity).

```
p:hover{border:2px solid red !important}

<body>
    <p style="border:2px solid green">foobar</p>
</body>
```

Browsers don't have a built-in CSS declaration for `p:hover` like they do for an `a:hover, a:active, a:visited`, etc; thus, the inline style in the HTML is the ONLY style being recognized at run-time. Unless... there's an `!important` available to give `:hover` a style.