# CSS declaration override

Tags: css

```
#header {
   width:100%;
   height:200px;
}

#theme.theme1 .handle {
   background:blue; 
} 

#header.noback { 
   background:none;   
}
```

why doesn't the last declaration override here ?

http://jsfiddle.net/5VnAs

Comment: Because the second rule is more specific.

Comment: Read here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637343/what-are-the-priorities-among-css-selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to **[CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)**. If you change the last rule to

```
#header.noback.handle{ 
   background:none;   
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5VnAs/2/)

it works