# How to adjust height of the selectpicker dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a selectpicker (bootstrap) in my page which options are loading dyanmically. It has a large number of list but not good to see. I want to reduce the height of the selectpicker. I have give inline style and all but it is not reflecting.

this is my code

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false" id="estType" name="estType">
   <option selected disabled value="0">Select</option>'
</select>
```

My js code

```
$function ({
    $.ajax({
        datatype: "json",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: "Establishment/GetPrePopulationDetails",
        success: function (result, success) {
            var esttypes = $.map(result['EstablishmentTypes'],
                function (key, value) {
                    return $('<option>', { value: value, text: key });
                });
            $('#estType').append(esttypes);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.error(xhr.status);
            console.error(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111652/how-do-you-set-the-max-height-of-an-expanded-chosen-element-jquery-plugin

Comment: Use `max-height` for that. My personal choice is to use media queries and have a `px` max height for desktop-type devices and a `vh` value for mobile devices. Also, if you have more than 20 children, consider using a [select2](https://select2.github.io/) or [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) solution.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I corrected it by myself...

Just add `data-size` in the html

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false" data-size="5" id="estType" name="estType">
   <option selected disabled value="0">Select</option>'
</select>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Using select element with Bootstrap 3. Here's a codePen example that demonstrates it – https://codepen.io/bencarp/pen/LdvOem

Comment: Very Thanx Dude

Answer (score 14):

Using [Bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), `data-size` doesn't work for me. I need to override CSS with this:

```
div.dropdown-menu.open{
  max-height: 314px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.dropdown-menu.inner{
  max-height: 260px !important;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Change the size as you like.

Comment: Is that a bootstrap dropdown?

Comment: @SoumyaMohan it's the dropdown created by Bootstrap Select library (see link in the answer)

Comment: in the given link, if we check options https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/ we can see that `size` attribute will do the job

Comment: Working docs link: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/

Answer (score 4):

I recently spent an hour trying to find how to restrict the height of a dropdown. Turns out the size attribute for select tags is set to 'auto' in the javascript file. For me, it was around line 369.

The solution is simple:

Set `size: '10'` //or however many options you want to be listed

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
   size: '10'
});
```

Comment: I added @am-evs I tested you code but isn't giving any response. What's the matter? `<select class="form-control" id="Year" name='established_year' style="size: '10';">`

Answer (score 3):

While maybe not what you're looking for, it is a great alternative.

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search

It allows for searching within the dropdown, therefore removing the need to adjust the height of the dropdown, plus it works with bootstrap.

Comment: Hi i got it from the link u shared.. set `data-size="5"`

Comment: No... It just give a hint.. I have added the answer.. but upvoted.. Thanks again

Comment: link is not available anymore

Answer (score 1):

you can use form-control-sm on select tag

```
     <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="processdef">
            <option>Process Def1</option>
            <option>Process Def2</option>
            <option>Process Def3</option>
            <option>Process Def4</option>
            <option>Process Def5</option>
      </select>
```