# Highlighting the font color of menu item of current page in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to highlight the current menu item in wordpress.  I have tried the following code:

```css
#menu-menu li.current-menu-item a { background-color:#d9707a; }
#menu-menu li.current_page_item a { background-color:#d9707a; }
```

The above code is working fine but what actually I am trying to do is highlight by changing the color, so I tried the following code but its not working

```css
#menu-menu li.current-menu-item a { color:#d9707a; }
#menu-menu li.current_page_item a { color:#d9707a; }
```

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know enough of your setup to know what the exact problem is. But it sounds to me that your `color` style might be being overwritten due to *style specificity*.

Either track down the style that is overwriting the `color` (using your browsers inspector) and change it there (but you need to confirm that it is safe to do so, as that style might be affecting other parts of your site) **OR**, the quick and dirty method of adding an `!important` tag to your styles.

**Example:**

```
#menu-menu li.current-menu-item a { color:#d9707a !important; }
#menu-menu li.current_page_item a { color:#d9707a !important; }
```

**More info on style specificity:**

[What are the priorities among CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637343/what-are-the-priorities-among-css-selectors) 
[Understanding CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514506/understanding-css-selectors)

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could have helped. Please don't forget to mark as answer if you feel it appropriate!

Comment: yes I tried to mark it as my accepted answer but stackoverflow said I have to wait for three more minutes :) Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem with color even with !important.  background-color works.